# re-enter function before exiting from it

Tags: c++, qt, function, connection, signals

I have a funcion `test()` that emits a signals `sig()`

```
class Game:
{
public: 
   Game();
   void test() 
       {.... 
        emit sig();
        connect(this,SIGNAL(sig()),this,SLOT(test()));
       };

signals:
    void sig();
}
```

I know that this code doesn't work and the program crashes because the`connect` re-enter into `test()` before exiting from it

When `test()` emits that signals I want to exit from `test()` and restart it, It's possible ?

Comment: Why does `connect` call `test`? What is `test` meant to do?

Comment: I call it test to make the question general... I have a void (here I called test) in wich I start a QStateMachine that play a game. When the game finish i have created a QMessageBox with two buttons and clicking one of this button I want to restart the game, so restart test()

Comment: The button gives me a signal sig() so I want to connect that signal with the function test() to restart it

Comment: This is bad design. If `test` runs for the duration of the game, then you must decide whether `test` can restart the game. If it can, then there is no reason for it to do so by calling `test` (or by calling something like `connect` which calls `test`). If it cannot, then `test` should terminate *before* some other code calls `test` to start the new game.

Comment: I know It's bar design... I created a widget. Now I have a void called match that start a new game i set game as central widget. But at the end of the game i want to restart it so I must re-call the function match but I'm never exited from it... So I want to exit from it before recalling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `connect(this,SIGNAL(sig()),this,SLOT(test()), Qt::QueuedConnection);`. The signal will schedule a call using the event queue of the thread.